# Where should "most" be in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Where would you most want to visit?

Where would you want to visit the most?

Can I also say *"Where do you most want to visit?"*

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatically, we normally put adverbial ***most*** after the relevant verb in such questions, so we're more likely to ask *Who do you like most?* rather than *Who do you most like?*

***But*** when the verb is part of a more extended "verb phrase", as in OP's *want to visit*, this puts greater distance between ***most*** and the specific verb it applies to *(want)*, so there's a tendency to move it to *before* the verb to maintain the semantic connection.

As to including the article ***the*** - I personally wouldn't<sup>1</sup>, but it's effectively a stylistic choice that has been [gaining traction in recent decades...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what%20I%20like%20most%2Cwhat%20I%20like%20the%20most&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhat%20I%20like%20most%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20I%20like%20the%20most%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Note that including the article only really works *after* the verb. Not many native speakers would endorse *Where would you **the** most want to visit?* (it's at the very least "clunky").

---

<sup>1</sup> Thanks to @TRomano below for prompting me to point out that my reluctance to include the article reflects the fact that if you restrict the above chart to the *British* corpus, that usage doesn't even occur enough to display on the chart. Which doesn't make it *wrong*, but it's not *my* first [stylistic] choice.

Comment: "Like the most" has had plenty of traction in the US for decades, but you won't necessarily see it in Ngram since it's the sort of thing that gets edited out of written texts. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+I+like+the+most%2Cone+I+like+most&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%20I%20like%20the%20most%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20I%20like%20most%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @TRomano: Well, the chart makes it obvious including the article is very much a minority usage even today (I assume you're not suggesting it's actually ***the most*** common form, even if we restrict ourselves to casual speech). But if you switch to BrE corpus on my graph, it also becomes pretty obvious why I said *I personally wouldn't [include it]* - in BrE, it doesn't even occur often enough to plot on the graph.

Comment: They look relatively close to me. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+I+like+the+most%2Cone+I+like+most&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%20I%20like%20the%20most%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20I%20like%20most%3B%2Cc0

Comment: We've obviously hit on a glitch in NGrams. When I switch your link to ***all*** English, the graph shows the "articled" version as mostly being on top until the 1960s. But I just tried to "drill down" to each date range below the graph (1800-1817, 1818, 1819, 1820-1957), and they *all* come back with "No results". Sometimes NGrams is just rubbish.

Comment: The drill-downs are especially unreliable; I suspect they're not drilling down into the data culled by the initial query, but into the Google-verse.  That aside, our initial queries differ significantly. I chose `one I like the most, one I like most` whereas you chose `what I like most,what I like the most`.  My sense is that **one** versus **what** makes a significant difference, though Google Ngram is probably not the tool to show it clearly. We need a database comprised of transcriptions of actual *conversational* English for a question like this.

Comment: @TRomano: Absolutely agree. But I *do* think that your search kinda *contextually* steers things towards including the article, since it's often going to reflect ***The** one I like [the] most...* I'd have liked to search for text more closely resembling OP's actual (question) context with *What do you like [the] most?*, but that's too many words for NGrams. And bizarrely, if I search for that text in Google Books, I get exactly the same "estimated results" (about 16,800) both with and without the article. Ho hum.

Comment: It would be interesting to plot the query contrastively against Who, What, Where, and When :)

Comment: I'm not very good at working [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/), but at least I can get it to show me 27 instances of *what i like most*, as compared to just 7 instances of *what i like **the** most*. They're all from 1990 or later though, so that doesn't tell us anything about *trends over time* (or any US/UK usage split, since COCA is only *American*).

Comment: I gave up on the COCA search interface a while ago. Life's too short.

Comment: After decades of soul-searching, I've finally decided that life is indeed to short too stuff a mushroom (but it turns out I can still find time to *eat* stuffed mushrooms if a competent chef "does the needful" :) But I don't really have time to evaluate any other potential candidates for my "non-bucket list". So at the moment my "Things life is too short for" list just contains two entries: *1: Stuffing mushrooms. 2: Extending this list.*