# What does "most" mean in "why do you most want to work here"?

Tags: adverbs, interpretation

Filling an interview form, I read the question

> Why do you most want to work here?

What exactly does "most" mean?

I read [Where should "most" be in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83096/where-should-most-be-in-this-sentence)
and it seems to suggest the sentence would be equivalent to

> Why do you want to work here most?

But I'm still at a loss interpreting it. Should I give my most compelling reason for wanting to work there or should I try to explain why, from all companies, that company is the one I most want to work in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rephrase more thoroughly it means :

> Which of your reasons for wanting to work here is most important to you?

It is a very standard question on job interviews, and something of a trap as one who is too exuberant about what a valuable employee s/he would be, may be rejected as insincere, and one who explains that the job has the best paycheck available may be deemed not motivated enough.

Comment: Thanks David, can you clarify on this bit: "one who is too exuberant about what a valuable employee s/he would be" > Wouldn't that mean that the candidate interpreted the question incorrectly as "why do you think we should hire you to work here?"

Comment: @LoremIpsum
 But while that is not the surface meaning o the question, in a sense every answer during a job interview should help answer the question "why should we hire you?", The question is not normally a test of English comprehension, but it is a test of the ability to respond quickly and properly.

Answer (score -1):

It is relative to you. In the terms of *your life.
"Why do you *most want to work here?"
*your is synonymous to *most.
Why do [you most] want to work here?